# Google contacts API using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to fetch Google contacts of a user. I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/jakemmarsh/5809963) code to implement auth2.

Here is my services.js

```
**Services.js** : ....
.service('googleService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($http, $rootScope, $q) {
var clientId = 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY',
scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full',
domain = '{OPTIONAL DOMAIN}',
deferred = $q.defer();

this.login = function () {
    console.log("Inside login()");
    gapi.auth.authorize({ 
        client_id: clientId, 
        scope: scopes, 
        immediate: false,
        approval_prompt: "force"
    }, this.handleAuthResult);
    return deferred.promise;
}

this.handleClientLoad = function () {
    console.log("Inside handleClientLoad()");
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.auth.init(function () { });
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
};

this.checkAuth = function() {
    console.log("Inside checkAuth()");
    gapi.auth.authorize({ 
        client_id: clientId, 
        scope: scopes, 
        immediate: true, 
    }, this.handleAuthResult);
};

this.handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
    console.log("Inside handleResult()");
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        var data = [];
        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
            var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                data.push(resp.email);
                data.push(authResult.access_token);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
        });
        
    } else {
        deferred.reject('error');
    }
};

this.handleAuthClick = function() {
    console.log("Inside handleAuthClick()");
    gapi.auth.authorize({ 
        client_id: clientId, 
        scope: scopes,
        immediate: false,
        approval_prompt: "force"
    }, this.handleAuthResult);
    return false;
};

this.makeContactList = function(root){
    var plist = [];
    var contactsList = root.feed.entry;     
    if (contactsList != null && contactsList.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < contactsList.length; i++) {
            var contact = contactsList[i];
            var fname = "";
            var l = contact.gd$email;
            var address = null;
            var emailArr = [];
            if (l != null && l.length > 0) {
                var el = l[0];
                if (el != null) {
                    address = el.address;
                }
                if (l.length > 1) {
                    for (var k = 1; k < l.length; k++) {
                        var e = l[k];
                        if (e != null) {
                            emailArr[k - 1] = e.address;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var lname = "";
            var dispName = contact.title.$t;
            if (dispName != null) {
                var sarr = dispName.split(' ');
                if (sarr.length > 0) {
                    if (sarr.length >= 1) {
                        fname = sarr[0];
                    }
                    if (sarr.length >= 2) {
                        for (var k = 1; k < sarr.length; k++) {
                            lname = lname +" "+sarr[k];
                        }
                        lname = lname.trim();
                    }
                }
            }
            var id = contact.id.$t;

            if (address != null && address.length > 0) {
                var p = {
                        firstName : "",
                        lastname : "",
                        email : "",
                        displayName : "",
                        otherEmails : [],
                        id : ""
                }
                p.firstName = fname;
                p.lastName = lname;
                p.email = address;
                p.displayName = dispName;
                p.otherEmails = emailArr;
                p.id = id;
                plist.push(p);
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No contacts were obtained from the feed");
    }
    return plist;
};
this.disconnectUser = function(access_token){
    var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +access_token;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : revokeUrl,
        async : false,
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(nullResponse){
            console.log("Successfully disconnected access_token");
        },
        error : function(e){
            console.log("Failed to isconnect access_token");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
}]);
```

and  controller.js

```
.controller('ContactsController',  ['$scope','$window','$modal','$http', 'ContactsFactory','googleService','ImportFactory','NotifyFactory', function($scope, $window, $modal, $http, ContactsFactory, googleService, ImportFactory, NotifyFactory) {

$scope.login = function () {
    var promise =  googleService.login()
    promise.then(function (data) {
        if(angular.isObject(data) && data[0]!== undefined && data[1]!== undefined){
            console.log(data[0]);
            console.log(data[1]);
            $http.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"+data[0]+"/full?alt=json&access_token=" + data[1] + "&max-results=1000&v=3.0")
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("In success");
                var contactList = googleService.makeContactList(data);
                var response = MyFactory.post(contactList);
                response.$promise.then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    NotifyFactory.success("Successfully synched with your google contacts!");
                    googleService.disconnectUser(access_token);
                    //$route.reload();
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("In error");
                console.log(data);
                NotifyFactory.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.11111111111");
            });
        }else{
            NotifyFactory.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.2222222222222");
        }
    }
    , function (err) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + err);
        NotifyFactory.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.333333333333");
    });
};
```

The $scope.login() is called when a user presses "Get Contacts" button.
This works fine in the sense that I some how get the contacts of the logged in google account.

When I press the button ,google's login screen pop up appear. I enter password of abc@gmail.com and press 'Accept', then  googleService.Login() returns an empty object and the error message is shown.

Then I press the Get contacts button again, the contacts of abc@gmail.com are fetched even before I press 'Accept' on the consent screen ( I have given an extra parameter in auth to force consent every time).I press 'Accept' on the consent screen

A third time I press the Get contacts button, contacts of abc@gmail.com are fetched again before I press Accept. I change the email on the consent screen to xyz@gmail.com and press accept.

Then I press the Get Contacts button a again and on the consent screen, concnt for abc@gmail.com is asked and not for xyz@gmail.com, I change it to xyz@gmail.com. Still the contacts of abc@gmail.com are being fetched on all subsequent presses of the Get Contacts Button.

I really dont understand the follow of control in the service or why my 'get contacts' thing is doing crazy things. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this fixes all your erros, but I'm pretty sure you should call `deferred.resolve(data);` in your `request.execute`s success handler, after data has been added to your data array:

```
this.handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
    console.log("Inside handleResult()");
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        var data = [];
        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
            var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                data.push(resp.email);
                data.push(authResult.access_token);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
        });
    } else {
        deferred.reject('error');
    }
};
```

Otherwise your login promise continues when the user is logged in but with the data array still being empty, what leads to an error.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem of error in the first try.
In subsequent attempts, contacts are being fetched before I press the Accept button on consent screen.

Comment: I think the access token is not being cleared. And google service get the contacts since there is a valid token.

Comment: Try revoking the token after fetching contacts: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/disconnect

Comment: I have made the changes from the link you gave. Access token was revoked successfully. But still the subsequent press to the get contacts button tries to fetch contacts with the old email and access_token before I even press the Accept button on google's consent screen. Wonder why this happens.

I can solve this problem by forcing a refresh with window.location.reload() function. Was wondering if its possible without reloading?

Comment: Might be because your `deferred` object is still resolved when you click get contacts the second time, so it instantly jumps into the `then` function. Try `deferred = $q.defer();` at the beginning of your `googleService`s `login` function.

Comment: Thank you :). That solved my problem.
I know how to yse $promise and resolve but I can't understand the concept of $q and defer(). etc. Could you suggest a tutorial. Official documentation doesn't help.

Comment: Just think of `$q.defer()` as a factory method which creates new deferred instances. I don't think you need `$q` for more than creating deferred objects.